# Retrieve multiple results set

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a Problem after I restive data from multiple result set I update the data and save it and its updated in Sql but  when I retrieve it again its bring the old data what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give many clues how you are doing this, and how you are doing the save (which might be important). However, a common gotcha here is using a local database file that is part of your project. If the project says "Copy Always", then every time you build it, the database is re-written from the unaltered state.

If that isn't the problem - are you perhaps leaving a transaction open?

(edit) Now that we've established that you are using LINQ-to-SQL; are you calling `SubmitChanges()`? It would also help to know whether you are using a single data-context, multiple data-contexts, or what? A data-context will only track changes in objects it created.

Comment: I have customer tabel&related tabels(customer addresses) in the database.I use stored procedure&LinqtoSql.
in my windform Ihave customer form that have datagridview(that views all customer in my database),textboxes for each field.
when need to retreive a spacifc customer you can click on any customer row in gridview which will retrive this customer information.If I edit this customer information and edit his address then save it I checked that data is updated in database.
if I retrived this customer again it will bring the oldest data for this customer but updated data for its address