# multiple result

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have multiple result set that return data form customer table(singlr record) and customer adresses(multiple records). when I retrive the data for first time it bring the correct data but when I update it and save the changes(Iam sure that the data are updated in database) it bring the old version for customer and the new data for customer addresses. I don't have any idea why is that

Comment: Could you post some relevant source code please? It is hard to answer your question without some more information.

Comment: See also these posts by same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790568/multiple-result-set | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790533/multiple-result-set | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790483/retrieve-multiple-results-set

Comment: Wafaa, you should try to "Edit" your existing question instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

With this limited information, and my limited knowledge of linqtsql
I only can provide a few leads:

- The customer table / recordset could have some sort of high concurrency setting / lock that prevents your update from being propagated.
- that way it is not necessarily not working, just being delayed.
- Put your update into a transaction and make sure it is committed. Then re-select
  your data. That way it either works, or you should get some errors.